# spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc Eample Application?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-jdbc, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to run "spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc" application. As my Source is RDBMS and I want to store the RDBMS data into RDBMS sink. I would like to know any best demo application based on "spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc".

Is there support for Incremental & Full load while performing Data Stream From RDBMS Source to RDBMS Sink using  "spring-cloud-starter-stream-jdbc".

Please share any reference blogs to understand "spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc" demo application.

Comment: Please share Spring Cloud Stream with JDBC Binder - source/sink Example or demo application

Answer (score 0):

You can use OOTB `jdbc` source/sink apps (with the binder of your choice rabbit, kafka). The `spring-cloud-starter-stream` projects are the ones you would want to use inside your application if you want to extend/build custom applications based on the jdbc starters.

For the OOTB apps, you can refer [here](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/). For instance, jdbc source app with rabbit binder can be found [here](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/jdbc-source-rabbit/)